# Sql Server Stored Procedure Case When in Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new in stored procedures.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MY_STORE_PROCEDURED]
(
@ID INT,
@NAME VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET    

WHEN
(( ID ) > 1)
THEN
ID=@ID 
,

NAME = @NAME 

END
```

I try to use when then for update my **ID** and `Name`

**If Id is greater than 1 i want to update otherwise no update.**

How can i do it ms sql?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In all SQL dialects, you can have a WHERE clause in your UPDATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MY_STORE_PROCEDURED]
(
@ID INT,
@NAME VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET NAME = @NAME
    WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

You do not need to check ID>1 since you are checking the equality with @ID. If you want to be sure that this doesn't happen if @ID <=1 then you may try the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MY_STORE_PROCEDURED]
(
@ID INT,
@NAME VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @ID > 1
        UPDATE MY_TABLE
        SET NAME = @NAME
        WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

Comment: If ID >=1 update otherwise dont update . İs it correct for my question ?

Comment: Well, i think it is too much. You are checking equality with @ID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to update. Are you trying to change the name on a user record with id = @ID?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MY_STORE_PROCEDURED]
(
@ID INT,
@NAME VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET Name = @Name
    WHERE Id = @ID and @ID > 1

END
```

Comment: Do you really want to set ALL records with an ID>1 to the same value?

Comment: It only makes any sense to change the ID if you feed in 2 parameters OldID and NewID, So you find the record with OldID, and change it to the new ID and Name. Perhaps you are in fact trying to insert a new record?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MY_STORED_PROCEDURE] ( @ID INT, @NAME VARCHAR(50) )
AS
BEGIN
    IF @ID > 1
        UPDATE MY_TABLE
        SET Name = @Name
        WHERE Id = @ID
END
```